# Flexible to import classes by conditions in Python

Tags: python

I have been meeting a problem when I inherit classes in Python.

I have 3 classes that contains test cases and a global variable is called `my_condition`.

```
global my_condition = 1

class mdl_test_case:
    def test_mdl_1():
        print "Testing MDL"

class feac_test_case:
    def test_feac_1():
        print "Testing FEAC"

class all_test_case():
    def test_common_1():
        print "Testing Common"
```

Now in the class `all_test_case`, I want to inherit class `mdl_test_case` or `feac_test_case` depending on the value of the variable `my_condition`.

Detail are below

- If I set `my_condition = 1` and call the class `all_test_case`. I expect to inherit the class `mdl_test_case`
- And vice versa, if I set `my_condition = 2` and call the class `all_test_case`. I expect to inherit the class `feac_test_case`

**Notes:**

- The varaible `my_condition` can change after each time calling the class `all_test_case`

Comment: Why not use the `unittest` framework and the [skipping decorators](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.skip)? That way you don't have to dynamically alter the inheritance tree (which is really not needed).

Comment: If i do like that it will be slow in running time due to filter and skipping. I have about 300 classes and 20000 test cases, so filtering and skipping is not a good solution for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can add updateClass function as follows:

```
class mdl_test_case:
    def test_mdl_1(self):
        print "Testing MDL"

class feac_test_case:
    def test_feac_1(self):
        print "Testing FEAC"

def updateClass(my_condition):
    global all_test_case
    if my_condition == 1:
        class all_test_case(mdl_test_case):
            def test_common_1(self):
                print "Testing Common"
    elif my_condition == 2:
        class all_test_case(feac_test_case):
            def test_common_1(self):
                print "Testing Common"
```

Now `all_test_case` will inherit from the class based on `my_condition`

```
updateClass(1)
ss = all_test_case()
ss.test_mdl_1()

updateClass(2)
ss = all_test_case()
ss.test_feac_1()  

# prints 
# Testing MDL
# Testing FEAC
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions but i have many variables like "my_condition" and many classes. So do as you suggested will make our code is very complicated and out of control. Maybe i need a better solution to resolve this case.